# How to create parallelogram shape Container in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation, flutter-test

I really don,t know how to create a parallelogram shape container in a flutter. I also found the flutter library for this but I can't use it because this is not supported by null safety.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use `transform` with `skewX` for this.

```dart
Container(
  width: 400,
  height: 100,
  transform: Matrix4.skewX(-.3),
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    border: Border.all(
      color: Colors.black,
    ),
    color: Colors.amber,
  ),
),
```

Answer (score -1):

For a shape like this you need to use `CustomPainter` for details on how to use it you can refer to [this](https://medium.com/flutter-community/a-deep-dive-into-custompaint-in-flutter-47ab44e3f216).

You can also use a website like [flutter shape maker](https://shapemaker.web.app/#/) for the same thing but to make it easier you can draw your shape and it'll auto generate the code for you.